# Gem installation error for non-root user

Tags: permissions, rubygems, centos, rvm

I did RVM single user installation on my CentOS server as root user, so rvm location is /usr/local.. However, now we have to use individual user accounts.
So now if I try to install a new gem, for instance -

1. > gem install linecache19 -v '0.5.12'
   >
   > ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
   >   You don't have write permissions into the /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@cams directory.
2. > sudo gem install linecache19 -v '0.5.12'
   >
   > /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/gem:12:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
   >       from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/gem:12

Point to note: I thought of re-installing the rubies and rvm with individual user account and do away with root installation. But I already have some apps running on the server as staging, so want to avoid this.

How can I solve these problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You obviously missed to read [RVM installation documentation](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) and overall [RVM docs](https://rvm.io/).

For part **1.** you need to run `rvmsudo rvm get stable` and add your users to **rvm** group.

For part **2.** do not use `sudo` it looses all environment settings - which leads to the error you see, either add your users to **rvm** group or run with `rvmsudo`.

Comment: I also happen to be behind firewall. I have the proxy added in bashrc, curlrc.But installation is still failing, seemingly due to connectivity issue -   ` /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `initialize': Connection timed out - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)`...  `Requesting http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.2-p320.tar.gz`  Running `http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.2-p320.tar.gz` from command line downloads the tar just fine so proxy is working.

Comment: this is unrelated issue, you could pass `--proxy ...` to rvm, this flags will be part of the call `curl -x ...`, the format is `<[protocol://][user@password]proxyhost[:port]>` (quoting `man curl`).

Comment: --proxy option is not helping.  Its only since I have started using non-root user that all these **rvm/bundle/gem-installations/proxy issues** are coming.As a root user, all was stable.  I have assigned my user account to all the groups shared by root.  `groups nraj  nraj : nraj bin daemon sys adm disk wheel apache rvm` `groups root  root : root bin daemon sys adm disk wheel`.

Comment: @nraj if it was working for root you need to make sure user has access to all the configuration/files that root had.

Comment: Thanks @mpapis. I will mark your answer as correct. Though I am still looking for the missing links between my root user config/files access and nraj user access.

Comment: you should not use `root` directly, also `sudo` should not use config files of the target user ...